# How to know exception occurred within grails transaction?

Tags: exception, grails, transactions

I have a service method which does some operation inside a transaction.

```
public User method1() {
    // some code...
    Vehicle.withTransaction { status ->
        // some collection loop
        // some other delete
        vehicle.delete(failOnError:true)
    }

    if (checkSomething outside transaction) {
        return throw some user defined exception
    }

    return user
}
```

If there is a runtime exception we dont have to catch that exception and the transaction will be rolled back automatically. But how to determine that transaction rolled back due to some exception and I want to throw some user friendly error message. delete() call also wont return anything.

If I add try/catch block inside the transaction by catching the Exception (super class) it is not getting into that exception block. But i was expecting it to go into that block and throw user friendly exception.

**EDIT 1:** Is it a good idea to add `try/catch` arround `withTransaction`

Any idea how to solver this?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to know how to catch an exception, determine what the exception is, and return a message to the user. There are a few ways to do this. I will show you how I do it.

Before I get to the code there are a few things I might suggest. First, you don't need to explicitly declare the transaction in a service (I'm using v2.2.5). Services are transactional by default (not a big deal).

Second, the transaction will automatically roll back if *any* exception occurs while executing the service method.

Third, I would recommend removing `failOnError:true` from `save()` (I don't think it works on `delete()`... I may be wrong?). I find it is easier to run `validate()` or `save()` in the service then return the model instance to the controller where the objects errors can be used in a flash message.

The following is a sample of how I like to handle exceptions and saves using a service method and try/catch in the controller:

```
class FooService {
    def saveFoo(Foo fooInstance) {
        return fooInstance.save()
    }

    def anotherSaveFoo(Foo fooInstance) {
        if(fooInstance.validate()){
            fooInstance.save()
        }else{
            do something else or
            throw new CustomException()
        }

        return fooInstance
    }

}

class FooController {
    def save = {
        def newFoo = new Foo(params)
        try{
            returnedFoo = fooService.saveFoo(newFoo)
        }catch(CustomException | Exception e){
            flash.warning = [message(code: 'foo.validation.error.message',
                    args: [org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e)],
                    default: "The foo changes did not pass validation.<br/>{0}")]
            redirect('to where ever you need to go')
            return

        }

        if(returnedFoo.hasErrors()){
            def fooErrors = returnedFoo.errors.getAllErrors()

            flash.warning = [message(code: 'foo.validation.error.message',
                    args: [fooErrors],
                    default: "The foo changes did not pass validation.<br/>${fooErrors}")]
            redirect('to where ever you need to go')
            return
        }else {
            flash.success = [message(code: 'foo.saved.successfully.message',
                                default: "The foo was saved successfully")]
            redirect('to where ever you need to go')
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, or gets some other input from more experienced Grails developers.

Here are a few other ways I've found to get exception info to pass along to your user:

```
request.exception.cause
request.exception.cause.message
response.status
```

A few links to other relevant questions that may help:

[Exception handling in Grails controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192336/exception-handling-in-grails-controllers)

[Exception handling in Grails controllers with ExceptionMapper in Grails 2.2.4 best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547486/exception-handling-in-grails-controllers-with-exceptionmapper-in-grails-2-2-4-be)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html

Comment: Thanks @CheddarMonkey. So you recommend surrounding the service call with try/catch. Then my "EDIT 1" in the question is correct way to do it??!!

Comment: You want the try/catch in the controller around the call to the service, like in the example where it wraps `returnedFoo = fooService.saveFoo(newFoo)`

Comment: Yeah but in our controllers we are trying to avoid try/catch and making it simple just make a call to service(s) and the service will put the response message which controller just needs to pass it on. Because in some scenarios we have many different calls to service api of different classes, then the controller will be populated by try/catches. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a problem having try/catch in the controllers. If that is your preference then my example won't work for you. I prefer this model because it delivers all the relevant error and exception messages to the controller where it can be rendered in the view. I can't think of a better way to get that info to a controller. If you come up with another solution please post it. I would be interested to see if there is an easier way to do this.