# Exception handling in groovy server pages

Tags: grails, exception, gsp

I have been searching the web for the issue I'm facing for quite some time now. I found people facing it, but couldn't get an appropriate solution to the problem. The issue is what would be the best way to handle any exception occurred in an `template.gsp` ? I know I can use a `try-catch` there so that my controller don't get the exception, but I did find people saying its not a good practice, but failed to answer why. So is it a wrong way and if it is then is there any better solution to deal with this problem ?

Comment: This question seems to be duplicate of [Exception handling in Grails controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192336/exception-handling-in-grails-controllers).

Comment: Thanks @Alidad for your quick look to the issue but my problem here is more towards the "programming do's and dont's"

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem with a simple code sample then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way is with a 500 error handler: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingToResponseCodes

If you have a lot of logic in your views that could produce a error consider refactoring the code into a tag library which can incorporate better error handling

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what behavior you want for your application with the error.

If a generic error page works for the application - then setup an error page in URL mappings and ignore the error in the controller.

Do you need a nice custom error that is specific for that case - (or possibly display an alternate page? ), if so then you'd need to a try catch (or do some fun with URL mapping and creating an error controller).  The objections that come up in [Exception handling in Grails controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192336/exception-handling-in-grails-controllers) arise around the amount of code required for the error handling in the controller vs the rest of the application - with the error handling code being ~40% of each controller method. This causes the code to seem bad/bloated (and apparently violate the CodeNarc "CatchException" rule).