# grails 3: is there a way to extract the duplicate boilerplate code in this API example?

Tags: api, grails3

We have to implement a large number of JSON API calls in a grails 3.3 web app.

Unfortunately, the build of each method is error handling, and currently we duplicate this code in each method which is a maintenance headache (if we improve error handing, we have to update 70+ methods). Is there a better way with less duplicate error code?  Some pattern which can extract the error checking code into one place?

FYI We use the super simple and effective object marshaller to render the json in the manner we need.  Unfortunately, the render(){...} pattern ignores object marshallers, so we need to use JSONBuilder in this case.

A correct login will give something like this:

```
{"result":"0","user":{"username":"bob","userId":"123"},"accounts":[{"balance":"0.00","currencyIso":"USD","id":1}]}
```

An error would look like this:

```
{"result":"9999","message":"exception in xxx"}
```

We have a long list of result codes (about 70) so the client knows exactly what the error was (We don't use HTTP status codes for this as they don't map at all)

```
class LoginCommand implements grails.validation.Validateable {
    String username
    String password
    static constraints = {
        username    nullable:false, blank: false, size: 3..32
        password    nullable:false, blank: false, size: 3..32
    }

}

class UserApiController {
 def login(LoginCommand cmd) {
    try {
        if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
            log.error("invalid parameters")
            render(status: 400, contentType: 'application/json') {
                    result 10
                    message "errors in parameters"
            return
            }
        } else {
            User user = User.findByUsernameAndPassword(cmd.username, cmd.password)
            def userAccounts = Account.findAllByUser(user)

            if (user == null) {
                render(status: 404, contentType: 'application/json') {
                    result 100
                    message "could not find user with that username and pass"
                }
            } else {

                def builder = new JSONBuilder()
                def json = builder.build {
                    result= "0"
                    user= {
                      username=user.username
                      userId=user.id
                    }
                    accounts=playerAccounts
                }
                render(status: 200, contentType: 'application/json', text: json)                
            } // else all good
        } // else params ok

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Caught Exception in UserApiController.login()", e)
        render(status: 500, contentType: 'application/json') {
                result 9999
                message e.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

We looked briefly at json views, but we don't think this helps us, adds complexity and as our project was not built using the rest-api we dont have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes that might help you:

- If you want the entire login functionality to be reused by multiple applications, consider creating a Grails Plugin. A plugin is a Grails-specific JAR project that can host reusable artefacts like Controllers and Services.

http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html

- You should set up a global error handler, rather than doing a generic `try...catch()` across your entire controller method. See:

[Exception handling in Grails controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192336/exception-handling-in-grails-controllers)

- If you want JSON Views, you can install it on an existing app, even if the app was not built using the REST profile. The JSON Views are very useful if you want to customize your output, but you also want separation of concerns between the Controller and View.

http://views.grails.org/latest/#_installation

- For this particular use case, you may also want to have a look at the Spring Security Grails plugins.

https://plugins.grails.org/q/spring-security

- To clean up your controller code, consider extracting your business logic to a service method. You can either create a standardized command object for your output, or use a custom RuntimeException subtype (MyLoginFailureException) to signal a failed login, passing back the reason and result code.